# swap one material with another

Tags: materials

is there a way to swap a material with another?

let`s say I have materials yellow, and gold, what I want is, to replace the material yellow, with the material gold, so all the objects that have the material yellow on it, to have the material gold instead.

In other words, material yellow to become material gold, and delete material yellow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the Outliner. At the top click the button and switch to Blender File. Still in the Outliner choose Materials, twirl it open with the little triangle to the left. You will now see all the materials in the file in a list. Now you just need to select the offending materials, right click it, choose Remap Users. And from the list choose the correct material. Now they will all link to the same correct material.

[image: Right click to show Outliner ID data Remap]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!

Comment: If you have lots of these, you may have to first remap 1, then select the reset and remap those, because otherwise it may reset the default New ID to some other material. By performing the remap once, it will remember the New ID for the following operations.

Answer (score 0):

Select your "Gold" material. In the Node editor, select all nodes <kbd>A</kbd> and copy them to the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>).

Select your "Yellow" material. In the node editor, select all nodes, delete them (<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Suppr</kbd>), then paste the clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>).

You can now delete the unused "Gold" material, then rename the "Yellow" material to "Gold".

Comment: Sorry, maybe i`m not clear enough. the fact is that I messed up the materials in a wery complex scene and now I have a lots of materials that have to be the same, like: ligt-blue, light-blue.001, light-blue.002, light-blue.003, ...etc. I need all these materials to become one.